Usage of "obvious" vs. "obviously"
I just ran across the following sentence:

Design thinking can be applied to a wide variety of fields, most
obvious the field of product and service innovation.

Dictionaries I searched don't mention this in their usage examples of the word.
Is this correct usage of the word "obvious" or should it be in the form of
"obviously", or should a word like "being" be added?
E.g.

Design thinking can be applied to a wide variety of fields, most
obvious being the field of product and service innovation.

or

Design thinking can be applied to a wide variety of fields, most
obviously the field of product and service innovation.


Or maybe a determiner was dropped: "the most obvious the field of product and service innovation."

It depends if the field is obvious, or applying design theory to that field is the most obvious thing to do. Let us know when you decide.
